# Jetpack Compose custom draggable BottomSheet tab shape design

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Design vs Actual. (Using Excalidraw)
[image: Design]
[image: Current Actual]

The issue I am facing is of zIndex inheritance.

```
    
   @Composable fun BottomSheetContainer() {
    val sheetState = rememberBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = BottomSheetValue.Collapsed
    )
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = sheetState
    )
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val tabHeight = 36.dp
    val modifier = Modifier
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(tabHeight).background(Color.White)) {
                Box(modifier = modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter).height(tabHeight/2+2.dp).width(130.dp).background(MaterialTheme.colors.background.copy(0.5f)).zIndex(1f))
            Row(modifier = modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(tabHeight/2, tabHeight/2, tabHeight/2, tabHeight/2)).height(tabHeight).align(alignment=Alignment.Center).background(Color.Blue)) {

                    Box(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .size(tabHeight)
                        .clip( RoundedCornerShape(tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2))
                        .background(Color.Red)
                        .zIndex(.3f))
Box(
                modifier = modifier.zIndex(4f)
                    .clip( RoundedCornerShape(tabHeight/2, tabHeight/2, 0.dp, 0.dp))
                    .width(100.dp)
                    .height(tabHeight)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    .background(color = purple400)

                    ,
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ){
                Text("^^^",color = Color.Black)
            }
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(tabHeight)
                        .clip( RoundedCornerShape(tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2,))
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background.copy(0.5f))
                )
            }}
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(400.dp)
                    .background(color = notepad),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Bottom sheet",
                    fontSize = 60.sp
                )
            }
        },
        sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.01f),
        sheetPeekHeight = 30.dp
    ) {
        //the bottom half of the screen, covered by sheet
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Button(onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    if (sheetState.isCollapsed) {
                        sheetState.expand()
                    } else {
                        sheetState.collapse()
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "Bottom sheet fraction: ${sheetState.progress.fraction}")
            }
        }
    }}
```

I need the row of
circle tab-rect circle to form the merge-shape.

an overlaying blocking-rect in front of row.background, but behind tab-rect.

Compose interprets blocking-rect.zIndex and compares to row's base zIndex rather than the tab-rect. Didn't work when I set it between the two

Also open to cleaner solutions c:

EDIT:
got it almost working, but it's not pretty. Outline and non-transparent
[image: Progress]

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheetContainer() {
    val sheetState = rememberBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = BottomSheetValue.Collapsed
    )
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = sheetState
    )
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val tabHeight = 36.dp
    val modifier = Modifier
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(tabHeight).background(Color.Transparent)) {
                Box(
                    modifier = modifier.zIndex(4f)
                        .clip( RoundedCornerShape(tabHeight/2, tabHeight/2, 0.dp, 0.dp))
                        .width(100.dp)
                        .height(tabHeight)
                        .align(Alignment.Center)
                        .background(color = notepad)

                    ,
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ){
                    Text("^^^",color = Color.Black)
                }
                Box(modifier = modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter).height(tabHeight/2+2.dp).width(130.dp).background(MaterialTheme.colors.background).zIndex(1f))
            Row(modifier = modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(tabHeight/2, tabHeight/2, tabHeight/2, tabHeight/2)).height(tabHeight).align(alignment=Alignment.Center).background(notepad)) {

                    Box(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .size(tabHeight)
                        .clip( RoundedCornerShape(tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2))
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
                        .zIndex(.3f))
                    Box(
                modifier = modifier.zIndex(4f)
                    .clip( RoundedCornerShape(tabHeight/2, tabHeight/2, 0.dp, 0.dp))
                    .width(100.dp)
                    .height(tabHeight)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    .background(color = notepad)

                    ,
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ){
                Text("^^^",color = Color.Black)
            }
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(tabHeight)
                        .clip( RoundedCornerShape(tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2,tabHeight/2,))
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
                )
            }}
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(400.dp)
                    .background(color = notepad),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Bottom sheet",
                    fontSize = 60.sp
                )
            }
        },
        sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        sheetPeekHeight = 30.dp
    ) {
        //the bottom half of the screen, covered by sheet
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Button(onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    if (sheetState.isCollapsed) {
                        sheetState.expand()
                    } else {
                        sheetState.collapse()
                    }
                }
            }) {

                Text(text = "Bottom sheet fraction: ${sheetState.progress.fraction}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol I just copied tab-rect within container Box just above blocking-rect. Seems to work but now changing color.white of container box to color.bg makes it ignore sheetPeekHeight ...idk will update when its looks right